# Need help understanding the following jQuery code in Socket.io(node.js)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

**html file**

```html
<script>
  var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });
</script>
```

```js
io.on( "connection", function(socket)
{
  console.log( "A user connected" );

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });

});
```

I dont understand this part of the code in jQuery syntax:

```
$('#m').val('');
return false;
```

Since I am already sending my socket input value through `socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());` why does the input field "m" (which is just an input field inside my form) need to be set to an empty string? and then the return false part after? The code runs fine and it is from [socket.io/chat](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/)

Please explain the jQuery side.

Comment: `$('#m')` sounds like the chat input message box. Makes sense to set it to empty once you send the message. `return false` stops the `<form>` element from submitting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking it line by line:

```
socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
```

This line sends the chat message as the value specified in the `#m` field.

```
$('#m').val('');
```

After the message is sent, this line clears out the value in the `#m` field.

```
return false;
```

Returning false stops the default event behaviour, which in this case stops the `form` element from submitting. You could also use `preventDefault()` on the passed in `event` if you prefer.